# Prolog from command line wont return true/false

Tags: prolog

The indication of a successful or failed goal won't print when compiling with the command line.

```
f(X,X) :- !, false.
f(0,1).
```

online compiler

```
?- f(0,1).
true
```

on the command line:

```
swipl -s prob4.pl -g 'f(0,1).' -t halt.
```

No output.

I already looked in the documentation and tried several flags but nothing worked so far. write does output into the terminal.

**Edit:**

```
problem(1):- write(1).
problem(N):-N>1, write(N), nl, M is N-1, problem(M).

print_true(F) :-
    forall(F, writeln(true)).

print_false(F) :-
    forall(\+ F, writeln(false)).

main :- 
    print_true(problem(3)),
    print_false(problem(3)),
    halt.
```

Managed to get output and the sucess or failure status as suggested. The problem now is that I am not able to print only the output of one of them.

Output:

```
3
2
1true
3
2
1
```

Comment: That `true` is from the interactive shell. In your program, use e.g. `write` to output whatever you want. If it's success vs failure, then you probably want to also use https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=halt/1 to set the exit status of a command.

Comment: Thanks @brebs i guess that did the trick, the way I've managed to do ain´t pretty but it works. now the output is printed twice with the status and i can´t find a way to prevent it.

Comment: "Not able"? All you need to do is rearrange your code a bit. Prolog has all the fundamental control structures available, e.g. https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=!/0 and https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(-%3E)/2

Comment: Working now with ->/2! thanks once again @brebs!